# I Need Duration Column in Order 8 am-9 am,...5 pm-6 pm

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need `Duration` column in order 8 am-9 am,...5 pm-6 pm I attached an image now currently it's getting like that how can I do to achieve.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationMaster](
    [Duration] [DateTime] NULL,
    [FromTime] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ToTime] [varchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
Go
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'08:00 AM - 09:00 AM', N'08:01', N'09:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'09:00 AM - 10:00 AM', N'09:01', N'10:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'10:00 AM - 11:00 AM', N'10:01', N'11:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'11:00 AM - 12:00 PM', N'11:01', N'12:00')

INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'12:00 PM - 01:00 PM', N'12:01', N'13:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'01:00 PM - 02:00 PM', N'13:01', N'14:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'02:00 PM - 03:00 PM', N'14:01', N'15:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'03:00 PM - 04:00 PM', N'15:01', N'16:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'04:00 PM - 05:00 PM', N'16:01', N'17:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'05:00 PM - 06:00 PM', N'17:01', N'18:00')
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [EMS].[USP_FetchFieldScoreCallReport]  
@StartDate datetime,  
@EndDate datetime,  
@UserID int,  
@EntityID int  
As  
Begin  

DECLARE @TblFormatedDate AS TABLE  
(  
    Duration varchar(20),  
    FromTime smalldatetime,  
    ToTime smalldatetime  
)  

INSERT INTO @TblFormatedDate  
SELECT Duration,  
--'2015-11-19 '+FromTime,  
CAST(@StartDate+FromTime as smalldatetime), CAST(+@EndDate+ToTime as smalldatetime)   
--'2015-11-19 '+ToTime  
 FROM DurationMaster  

--SELECT * FROM @TblFormatedDate  

--select top 20 * FROM EMS.tbl_event (NOLOCK)  

-- ORDER BY fld_event_created_on DESC  


select CreatedBy.fld_user_full_name AS CreatedUser,FormatedDate.Duration,COUNT(Event.fld_event_id ) AS LogACallCount,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Fax Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FaxSent,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Contract Prepared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As ContractPrepared,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Hot Lead' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As HotLead,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Email Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EmailSent  

FROM EMS.tbl_event (NOLOCK) AS Event   
INNER JOIN EMS.tbl_user AS CreatedBy (NOLOCK) ON CreatedBy.fld_user_id = Event.fld_event_created_by_id  
LEFT JOIN @TblFormatedDate AS FormatedDate   
ON Event.fld_event_created_on BETWEEN FormatedDate.FromTime AND FormatedDate.ToTime  

WHERE fld_event_isactive=1 AND Event.fld_event_status = 'Completed' AND  fld_event_created_by_id IN(@UserID)  
AND Event.fld_event_istask=1 AND Event.fld_event_entity_id =100100  
 AND Event.fld_event_isactive = 1   
 AND FormatedDate.Duration is not null  
 GROUP BY FormatedDate.Duration, CreatedBy.fld_user_full_name  

END
```

When axecute stored procedure I am getting this grid:

[image]

Comment: Store your data either as time column or datetime, then it will sort correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't use NOLOCK everywhere either: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You also claim that the `Duration` field is datetime, but then you insert values like  '08:00 AM - 09:00 AM' which will definitely fail

Comment: I Want To Arrange Duration Column

Comment: [Duration] [varchar] (25) NULL,

Comment: Like I said, you should use time / date fields. Using varchar to store date or time related data will cause you problems, especially if you want to calculate something.

Comment: Hi James  Kindly Check Enclosed Image I am Getting Data I Need To Arrange Duration Column only How Do I Achieve In Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationMaster](
[Duration] VARCHAR(20) NULL,
[FromTime] TIME NULL,
[ToTime] TIME NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
Go

INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES(N'08:00 AM - 09:00 AM', N'08:01', N'09:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'09:00 AM - 10:00 AM', N'09:01', N'10:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'10:00 AM - 11:00 AM', N'10:01', N'11:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'11:00 AM - 12:00 PM', N'11:01', N'12:00')

INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'12:00 PM - 01:00 PM', N'12:01', N'13:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'01:00 PM - 02:00 PM', N'13:01', N'14:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'02:00 PM - 03:00 PM', N'14:01', N'15:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'03:00 PM - 04:00 PM', N'15:01', N'16:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'04:00 PM - 05:00 PM', N'16:01', N'17:00')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationMaster] ([Duration], [FromTime], [ToTime]) VALUES (N'05:00 PM - 06:00 PM', N'17:01', N'18:00')

Go

CREATE PROCEDURE [EMS].[USP_FetchFieldScoreCallReport]  
@StartDate datetime,  
@EndDate datetime,  
@UserID int,  
@EntityID int  
As  
Begin  

DECLARE @TblFormatedDate AS TABLE  
(  
    Duration varchar(20),  
    FromTime time,  
    ToTime time  
)  

INSERT INTO @TblFormatedDate  
SELECT Duration,   
@StartDate+FromTime, @EndDate+ToTime --datetime + time = datetime. No cast needed
 FROM DurationMaster  

select CreatedBy.fld_user_full_name AS CreatedUser,FormatedDate.Duration,COUNT(Event.fld_event_id ) AS LogACallCount,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Fax Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FaxSent,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Contract Prepared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As ContractPrepared,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Hot Lead' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As HotLead,  
Sum(Case when fld_event_subject='Email Sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EmailSent  

FROM EMS.tbl_event (NOLOCK) AS Event   
INNER JOIN EMS.tbl_user AS CreatedBy (NOLOCK) ON CreatedBy.fld_user_id = Event.fld_event_created_by_id  
INNER JOIN @TblFormatedDate AS FormatedDate   
ON Event.fld_event_created_on BETWEEN FormatedDate.FromTime AND FormatedDate.ToTime  

WHERE fld_event_isactive=1 AND Event.fld_event_status = 'Completed' AND  fld_event_created_by_id IN(@UserID)  
AND Event.fld_event_istask=1 AND Event.fld_event_entity_id =100100  
AND Event.fld_event_isactive = 1   
--AND FormatedDate.Duration is not null  --Wih this condition is an Inner Join.. so use it!
GROUP BY FormatedDate.Duration, CreatedBy.fld_user_full_name  
 Order By FormatedDate.FromTime
END
```

Comment: Plz Check http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125623/i-need-duration-column-in-8-am-9-am-5-pm-6-pm

Comment: Is it possible to format you answer?  As is; it's hard to read.  Here's a handy guide from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Could u Connect To My PC NOW